# Retrieving pk from filtered Django QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset, searchqueryset

I have a `Sample` model that is searched via a web interface and a QuerySet of criteria-matching Sample objects are returned as expected.

**model**

```
class Sample(models.Model):
   sample_name = models.CharField('Sample', max_length=16)
```

**html form**

```
<form name="sample_search_form" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
     <input  id="sample_search_box" type="text" name="sample_search_box"  placeholder="Search samples..." >
      <button id="sample_search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views**

```
def search(request):
   if request.GET:
      search_term = request.GET['sample_search_box']
      results = Sample.objects.filter(sample_name__icontains=search_term)                                  
      return render_to_response('samples/sample_search_list.html', {'results': results}) 
   return render_to_response('samples/sample_search_list.html', {'results': results, 'search': results})
```

I would also like to return the models' primary key for additional purposes.

I tried variations on below.

```
      results = Sample.objects.filter(sample_name__icontains=search_term).get(sample_name_id=pk)
```

But I get an error similar to:
`name 'pk' is not defined`

How can I guard the filtration method as written AND also get the primary key value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just iterate over the `results`, and for every `element`, you obtain the `element.pk` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to how you access the `sample_name` field, there is also a `pk` field you can access:

In Python code:

```
for sample in results:
    print(sample.pk)
```

Or, in your template code:

```
{% for result in results %}
    {{ result.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the actual database column name of the `pk` may be different (it is usually `id`) but Django always makes the `pk` shortcut available.